# Java swing Loader image not displaying properly?

Tags: java, swing, awt, event-dispatch-thread

I have tried the below code . 
Functionality-

1. Click on Button
2. It will call a method which will take some time to process.
3. Need to display Loader image so that user can see that processing is going on.

I tried below but if the `loaderLabel1.setVisible(true);` before method call doesnot show image and if we comment `loaderLabel1.setVisible(false);` then it shows loader image after method is finished.

Will `actionPerformed` method not apply the visibility to Label unless it completes? If yes is there any alternative for this problem?

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestLoader extends JPanel{


    static ImageIcon loading1 = new ImageIcon("D:\\WORKSPACE\\STUDY\\images\\ajax-loader.gif");



    static JLabel loaderLabel1 = new JLabel(loading1, JLabel.CENTER);


    public TestLoader(){
        super(new GridLayout(0, 1));        
        System.out.println("---------TEST ------");

        JPanel submitPanel = new JPanel();
        submitPanel.add(clearMessageButton);
        this.add(submitPanel);

        JPanel LOADER_PANEL = new JPanel();
        loaderLabel1.setVisible(false);
        LOADER_PANEL.add(loaderLabel1);
        this.add(LOADER_PANEL);
    }


    JButton clearMessageButton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Test Result") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            loaderLabel1.setVisible(true);

            TestMethod();

            loaderLabel1.setVisible(false);

        }});

    public void TestMethod(){
        System.out.println(" =========START  TestMethod =========");
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(" =========complete  TestMethod =========");
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TestLoader pf = new TestLoader();
                pf.display();
            }
        });


    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TEST LOADER");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Threading problem: do not perform processing on the Event Dispatch Thread. The `setVisible(true)` call puts an event on the event queue, and it is performed after the `actionPerformed()` method returns...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto : Thanks for the information. Using SwingWorker finally solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the class SwingWorker that allows you to perform Tasks in a different thread; here's an example of how your code could be changed to use a SwingWorker:

```
JButton clearMessageButton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Test Result") {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                loaderLabel1.setVisible(true);
                TestMethod();
                return true;
            }

            public void TestMethod() {
                System.out.println(" =========START  TestMethod =========");
                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(" =========complete  TestMethod =========");
            }

            protected void done() {
                loaderLabel1.setVisible(false);
            };
        };
        worker.execute();
    }
});
```

Note the methods doInBackground() that does the work in the other thread and done() that is called after doInBackground() is finished.

Comment: This solved my problem . Thank you for the help .